# Is it possible to write to multiple sheets using data type "data:application/vnd.ms-excel"

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I have a webpage that is downloading a HTML table by first creating the excel file using "**var excelfile = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';**" and generating a link to save the excel file with the table information.

However I am now displaying a second table and wish to save this on a second sheet in the generated excel file. Is it possible to do this using the method or should I start looking into another way of generating the excel file to allow me to generate the second sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By saving an html file with xls extension, you can't create multiple sheets, because the excel file is not a real excel file. It is actually an HTML file and MS Excel knows to open html and display it.

In order to create multiple sheets, I see two possible options:
1. **Best option**: Use an Excel library for JavaScript, like [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)
2. Save the file in [Spreadsheet XML file format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx).

Comment: Thanks very much for the input it's much appreciated!